# How to add, update, or delete quotation table rows in edit page using Laravel 10?

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel

I'm developing a quotation generator that allow users to automate quotation generation. Within my database, this is what the structure would look like:

[image: model structure]

For the edit form, this is what it looks like on web:

[image: Form example]

This is the html for the items table only within the edit form:

```
<table id="item_table" class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th width="5%">Sr No.</th>
    <th width="15%">Items</th>
    <th width="30%">Description</th>
    <th width="10%">Value</th>
    <th width="5%">Quantity</th>
    <th width="10%">Total</th>
    <th width="3%"></th>
</tr>
@foreach( $selected_items as $item_sel )
<tr id="row_id_{{ $counter }}">
    <td><span id="sr_no">{{ $counter }}</span></td>
    <td>
        <select name="titles[]" id="titles_{{ $counter }}" class="titles form-control input-sm" onchange="Populate(this.value, this.id)">
            <option value="0">Select items...</option>
            <!-- Dynamic Items from database -->
            @foreach( $items as $item )
                @if($item->title !== $item_sel->title)
                    <option value="{{ $item }}">{{ $item->title }}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
            <option value="{{ $item_sel }}" {{ ($item_sel) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $item_sel->title }}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="descriptions[]" id="descriptions_{{ $counter }}" readonly class="form-control input-sm" value="{{ $item_sel->description }}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="values[]" id="values_{{ $counter }}" data-srno="{{ $counter }}" class="form-control input-sm number-only values" value="{{ $item_sel->value }}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_{{ $counter }}" data-srno="{{ $counter }}" class="form-control input-sm number-only quantity" value="{{ $item_sel->quantity }}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_{{ $counter }}" data-srno="{{ $counter }}" readonly class="form-control input-sm number-only total" value="{{ $item_sel->total }}" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_sel[]" id="item_sel[{{ $counter }}]" value="{{ $item_sel->id }}" />
    <td><input type="button" name="remove_row" id="{{ $counter++ }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove_row" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .25rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: .5rem; --bs-btn-font-size: .75rem;" value="X"></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
<div align="right">
   <button type="button" name="add_row" id="add_row" class="btn btn-outline-success add_row" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .25rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: .5rem; --bs-btn-font-size: .75rem;">+</button>
</div>
```

The javascript that controls the table, which I believe affects the auto-populate function for the edit, ex; when I select a title, the description and value fields wouldn't automatically would be filled when adding a new row:

```
<script>
let myOptions = '@foreach( $items as $item )<option value="{{ $item }}">{{ $item->title }}</option>@endforeach';

$(window).on("load",function(){
    let final_total = $('#final_total').text();
    let count = --document.getElementById("item_table").rows.length;
    console.log(count);
    let value;

    // Add new table rows
    $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
        ++count;
        $("#total_items").val(count);
        let html_code = '';

            html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
            html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';
            html_code += '<td><select name="titles[]" id="titles_'+count+'" class="titles form-control input-sm" onchange="Populate(this.value, this.id)">';
            html_code += '<option value="0">Select items...</option>'+ myOptions +'';
            html_code += '</select></td>';
            html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="descriptions[]" id="descriptions_'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm" /></td>';
            html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="values[]" id="values_'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number-only values" /></td>';
            html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number-only quantity" /></td>';
            html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm number-only total" /></td>';
            html_code += '<td><input type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-outline-danger remove_row" style="--bs-btn-padding-y: .25rem; --bs-btn-padding-x: .5rem; --bs-btn-font-size: .75rem;" value="X"></td>';
            html_code += '</tr>';

        $("#item_table").append(html_code);
    });

    function calculate_final_total(count){
        let final_total = 0;

        for(var j=1; j<=count; j++)
        {
            var quantity = 0;
            var values = 0;
            var total = 0;
            
            values = $("#values_"+j).val();
            if (values > 0) {
                quantity = $("#quantity_"+j).val();
                if (quantity > 0){
                    total = parseFloat(values) * parseFloat(quantity);
                    $("#total_"+j).val(total);
                }
            }
        }

        $(".total").each(function(){
            final_total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });

        $("#final_total").val(final_total);
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function() {
        var rowId = $(this).attr('id'); // Get the ID attribute of the clicked button
        var row = document.getElementById('row_id_' + rowId); // Get the row element by its ID // Get the row element by its ID
        var hiddenInput = document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name^="item_sel"]');

        if (hiddenInput) {
            hiddenInput.name = 'deleted_items[]';
            row.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the row by setting its display property
            count--;
            $("#total_items").val(count);
            calculate_final_total(count);
        } else {
            // If there's no hidden input, simply remove the row from the DOM
            $('#row_id_' + rowId).remove();
            count--;
            $("#total_items").val(count);
            calculate_final_total(count);
        }

        console.log(rowId);
    });

    $(document).on('blur','.values',function(){
        calculate_final_total(count);
    });
    
    $(document).on('blur','.quantity',function(){
        calculate_final_total(count);
    });
});

function Populate(value, id){
    var selectID = id.split('_')[1];
    console.log(selectID);
    //console.log(JSON.parse(value).id);
    document.getElementById("descriptions_"+selectID).value = JSON.parse(value).description;
    document.getElementById("values_"+selectID).value = JSON.parse(value).value;
}
</script>
```

For inserting data, there were struggles but I manage to solve the problem, so here is the function for insert in controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    // echo dump(count($request->titles));
    // echo dump($id = Auth::id());
    // echo dump(json_decode($request->titles[1])->id);
    // echo dd($request->all());

    $errorMessages = [
        'title.required' => 'Project title is required!',
        'description.required' => 'Project description is required!',
        'client_name.required' => 'Client name is required!',
        'client_email.required' => 'Client email is required!',
        'client_email.email' => 'Client email must be valid!',
        'client_address.required' => 'Client address is required!',
    ];

    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'client_name' => 'required',
        'client_email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns',
        'client_address' => 'required',
    ], $errorMessages);

    $quotation = Quotation::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'client_name' => $request->client_name,
        'client_email' => $request->client_email,
        'client_address' => $request->client_address,
        'final_total' => $request->final_total,
        'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at'=>Carbon::now(),
        'owner_id' => Auth::id(),
    ]);

    
    $count=0;
    $titles = $request->titles;
    $quantities = $request->quantity;
    foreach ($titles as $items){
        $item_quantity = $request->quantity[$count];
        $item_decode = json_decode($items, true);
        $item = QuotationItem::create([
            'title' => $item_decode['title'],
            'description' => $item_decode['description'],
            'value' => $item_decode['value'],
            'quantity' => $item_quantity,
            'total' => $item_decode['value'] * $item_quantity,
            'quotation_id' => $quotation->id,
            'created_at'=>Carbon::now(),
            'updated_at'=>Carbon::now(),
        ]);
        $count++;
    }

    return redirect()->route('user.quotations.create')
        ->with('message','Quotation created successfully.');
}
```

The problem I'm facing now is the updating part. For this function, the scenario that I want to achieve is, when the user is editing the items table, they can either update the existing table row, add a new row, or delete a row that exist. But the problem is, anytime I tried doing any of the actions, it doesn't change anything in the database.

This is the function for update:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // echo dump(count($request->titles));
    // echo dump($id = Auth::id());
    // echo dump(json_decode($request->titles[1])->id);
    echo dd($request->all());

    // $request->validate([
    //     'title' => 'required',
    //     'description' => 'required',
    //     'client_name' => 'required',
    //     'client_email' => 'required',
    //     'client_adress' => 'required',
    // ]);

    $quotation = Quotation::where('id', $request->id)
    ->update([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'client_name' => $request->client_name,
        'client_email' => $request->client_email,
        'client_address' => $request->client_address,
        'final_total' => $request->final_total,
        'updated_at'=>Carbon::now(),
    ]);

    $count=0;
    $item_sel_length = sizeof($request->item_sel);
    $titles = $request->titles;
    $quantities = $request->quantity;

    foreach ($titles as $items){
        $item_decode = json_decode($items, true);
        $item_quantity = $request->quantity[$count];
        
        if($item_sel_length > $count){
            $item = QuotationItem::where('id', $request->item_sel[$count])->update([
                'title' => $item_decode['title'],
                'description' => $item_decode['description'],
                'value' => $item_decode['value'],
                'quantity' => $item_quantity,
                'total' => $item_decode['value'] * $item_quantity,
                'quotation_id' => $request->id,
            ]);    
        }else{
            $item = QuotationItem::updateOrCreate([
                'title' => $item_decode['title'],
                'description' => $item_decode['description'],
                'value' => $item_decode['value'],
                'quantity' => $item_quantity,
                'total' => $item_decode['value'] * $item_quantity,
                'quotation_id' => $request->id,
            ]);
        }
        $count++;
    }

    // Process deleted items
    $deletedItems = $request['deletedItems'];
    foreach ($deletedItems as $deletedItem) {
        $itemToDelete = QuotationItem::find($deletedItem['id']);
        if ($itemToDelete) {
            $itemToDelete->delete();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('user.quotations.index')
        ->with('message','Quotation updated successfully.');
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Sorry if the post is long, but I don't know where to turn to.

Comment: show your backend code

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not show all your code, so lets pretend all your fontend code works

i suggest you use Laravel route model binding

so your route should look like this

```
Route::controller(QuatationController::class)->group(function(){
     Route::put('/quatation/{quatation:id}', 'update');
});
```

then in your controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Quatation $quatation)
{
  $validated = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required',
    'client_name' => 'required',
    'client_email' => 'required',
    'client_address' => 'required',
  ]);

  $quotation->update($validated);
  $quotation->items()->delete();
 
  $titles = $request->titles;
  $quantities = $request->quantity;
  foreach($titles as $item){
   $quotation->items()->create([
       'title' => $item['title'],
       'description' => $item['description'],
       'value' => $item['value'],
       'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
       'total' => $item['value'] * $item['quantity'],
    ])
  }
  return redirect()->route('user.quotations.index')->with('message','Quotation updated successfully.');
}
```

the above code use Eloquent relationship so you must specify relationship in your Quatation model like below

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(QuatationItem::class);
}
```

and your request parameters of your PUT request should look like this

```
{
   title : 'qwe',
   description : 'qwedsf',
   client_name : 'adfaf',
   client_email: 'asdasd@gmail.com',
   client_address: 'address',
   titles : [
        {
          title : 'title',
          description : 'description',
          value : 'value',
          quantity : '2'
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I will revise my question because I didn't provide additional details